# $a+b=2$ and $|a|<|b|$; $|a|<1<|b|\Leftrightarrow -3<ab<1$

Tags: inequality

Let a and b be two reals such that $a+b=2$ and $|a|<|b|$

the question is to show that $$|a|<1<|b|\Leftrightarrow -3<ab<1$$

I gave it about two hours trying to solve it but in vain. Any hint would be great.

**Attempt :** we have $ -3<ab<1\Leftrightarrow -2<ab+1<2$, so i tried to start from $|a|<1<|b|$ and try to find $-2<ab+1<2$.

$|a|<1<|b|$ implies $ab+|a|<ab+1<ab+|b|$. if $b$ is positive (if i succed ill treat the other case) we get $ab+|a|<ab+1<ab+b$. from here i tried to concentrate on $ab+b$ and use that $a+b=2$ to find  $ab+b<2$

$2-(ab+b)=2-(2-b)b-b=b^2-3b+2$. but this quantity is negative between 1 and 2 and positive above 2, and i know only that $b>1$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're much more likely to get answers that speak directly to your problem if you include a record of what you have done already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b=2-a$ and $|a|<|b|$ then $a<1, b>1$ or $a>1, b<1$. (1)

If $|a|<1<|b|$ and (1), then $a<1, b>1$. (2)

$ab=a(2-a)=2a-a^2=1-(a-1)^2<1$

$|a|<1$ means $-1<a<1$ then $ab=a(2-a)=2a-a^2=1-(a-1)^2>1-4=-3$.

Comment: The first line requires a proof, especially since "or $a>1,b<1$" is weird. Same critics (oddity and lack of proof) for the second line, since $a<1,b>1$ is in fact a direct consequence of $|a|<|b|$ and does not require $a|<1<|b|.$ Finally, this answer only treats one direction of the equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=2-a$. The hypothesis $|a|<|b|$ can be rewritten $a^2<(2-a)^2,$ which (after development and simplification) is equivalent to $a<1.$ This entails :

- $b=2-a>2-1=1$ and *a fortiori* $|b|>1$ ;
- $|a|<1$ if and only if $a>-1$ ;
- $ab=P(a)<P(1)=1$, since the [quadratic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) $x\mapsto P(x):=2x-x^2$ is increasing on $(-\infty,1).$

Note also that $P(-1)=-3.$

The equivalence to be proved (under the assumption $|a|<|2-a|$, i.e. $a<1$) thus reduces to
$$a>-1\Leftrightarrow P(a)>P(-1).$$
Again, this is a consequence of the fact that $P$ is increasing on $(-\infty,1).$